Как сделать рандомные атаки боссу в Unity 2D?
Я создаю простенькую 2D игру для мобильных устройств, и мне нужен босс. Хочется реализовать какие то 5 базовых атак, например, взмах мечом, сильный удар и т.д., но так, чтобы он атаковал рандомно. Т.е. из 5 заранее готовых атак выбирал рандомную и воспроизводил её, и повторял так до момента пока его не победят. Атаки должны быть сделаны заранее, и просто повторяться, рандомно призываясь с помощью скрипта. Если что игра не TopDown.
К данному вопросу не относится генерация в рандомном месте.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как исключить генерацию нескольких предметов в одном месте?

Хоть название немного другое, но суть одна ↑↑↑

Алексей вопросы совершенно разные.

Суть у них одна - сгенерировать рандомно что-то без повторений.

А если можно с повторениями - то вообще проблемы не вижу. Берёшь Random из Юнити и применяешь к массиву.

Твоя задача элементарная. В итоге сводится к применению одной конкретной функции из документации. По сути вопрос можно закрывать

attack = attacks[Random.Range(0, attacks.Length - 1)];

private void Awake()
{
StartCoroutine("attack"+Random.Range(0, 4));
}

private IEnumerator attack0()
{
yield return null;
//код
}

//далее так еще 4 атаки лелаешь, задержку можно сделать через yield return new WaitForSeconds

Наверное код рабочий, но это не точно)
